# Rotate a div towards the direction of the mouse using atan2()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, math

I would like the mouse to `align` with the `top` of the div and the div should `rotate` when the mouse moves with the top part of the div aligned with the mouse. I want to use `atan2`. It should look something like [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/atan2/1244274107).

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var stick = $(".stick"), sHeight = stick.outerHeight(), 
                sWidth = stick.outerWidth(), atan,
                sTop = stick.offset().top, sLeft = stick.offset().left;

    $(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        // console.log(e.pageX, " ", e.pageY)
        atan = Math.atan2(e.pageY - sTop , e.pageX - sLeft ) 
        console.log(atan)
        stick.css({"transform" : "rotate("  + atan +  "rad)"} )
    })
})
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid green;
}
.stick{
    width: 3px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background: green;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="stick"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made something that works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fobheh7d/).

It seems you're not centring properly - you need to take into account the width of the div and the centre point of the container

```
div.$(function(){

    var stick = $(".stick"), sHeight = stick.outerHeight(), 
                sWidth = stick.outerWidth(), atan,
                sTop = stick.offset().top, sLeft = stick.offset().left;
    $(document).on("mousemove", function(e){
        atan = Math.atan2(e.pageY - 200 , e.pageX - 250) + Math.PI/2;
        console.log(atan);

        stick.css({"transform" : "rotate("  + atan + "rad)"} );


    });
});
```

(I also removed the rotation in the css, and positioned the stick in the centre.)

Comment: I see this works and thanks for your response. First thing that I don't understand is why you nee "Math.PI/2". I know that equals to 90 degrees. then Im thinking why the container needs to be in play(-200, -250 for centering). because the container is just really there for the border style. I just thought i need 2 sides to get angle for atan2() and then rotate.

Comment: The point (250, 200) is the centre of the stick - so you're rotating by the angle from that point to the mouse. You rotate by 90 because the stick is initially vertical, but the angle 0 is horizontal to the right.

Comment: Sorry to keep this question open but its bothering me that I can get it to work with one of the ends of the div pinned down. With your answer it looks like the rotation origin is in the center and I'm trying to get it to the bottom(edge). like here.  https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/atan2y-x-processingjs/6206505994420224 . Thanks In advance.

Comment: Hi, I made another question pertaining to  the question I ask in my last comment. Please help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459736/how-do-i-get-this-div-to-rotate-from-one-of-its-end-and-not-its-center-using-ata

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the angle computation `phi=atan2(y,x)` assumes a "normal" Cartesian coordinate system where the `y` axis points upwards. In screen coordinates, it points downwards. Thus you should use `phi=atan2(-y,x)`.

But to be sure you should try out and report where the bar points to when using rotations `0deg` and `90deg`. With your code the rotation center is the middle of the bar, so orientation is difficult to determine, but it seems that `0deg` points upwards and angles are applied clockwise. Thus for the inner coordinate system, where 0° is the X axis and 90° the Y axis, `X = centery-y` and `Y=x-centerx`, thus

```
angle = atan2(x-centerx, centery-y)
```