# How do I get this div to rotate from one of its end and not its center using atan2()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, rotation

I don't want the `div.stick` in the code below to be rotating according to the center of the stick. Right now it looks like the rotation origin is in the center I want the rotation origin to be at the bottom. The stick should rotate when the mouse moves and when the mouse is aligned with the top of the stick.  It should look something  like [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/atan2y-x-processingjs/6206505994420224) (rotate-origin is at the bottom)

Javascript:

```
var stick = $(".stick"), sHeight = stick.outerHeight(), 
                           sWidth = stick.outerWidth(), atan,
                           sTop = stick.offset().top, sLeft = stick.offset().left,
                           middle = sTop + sHeight / 2,
                           bottom = sTop + sHeight;
                           console.log(sTop, " ", sLeft)
       $(document).on("mousemove", function(e){
           atan = Math.atan2(e.pageY - 200, e.pageX - 250 ) + Math.PI/ 2 ;
            $(".display").html("atan" + atan)

           stick.css({"transform" : "rotate("  + atan + "rad)"} )


       })
```

HTML:

```
<div class="display"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="stick"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid green;
}
.stick{
    width: 3px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important part is to reset the center of rotation. Add to CSS `.stick`

```
transform-origin: 50% 100%;
```

to have the middle of the bottom as rotation center. Now you need to adapt the angle computation to be relative to this new center. Add new variables

```
var sRotMidX = sLeft+sWidth/2, sRotMidY=sTop+sHeight;
```

and change the angle computation to

```
atan = Math.atan2(e.pageY - sRotMidY , e.pageX - sRotMidX) + Math.PI/2;
```

---

Or to not have multiple sources for the same quantity, and the center at a 9:1 split:

```
var fmidX =.5, fmidY=.9;
stick.css({"transform-origin" : (100*fmidX)+"% "+(100*fmidY)+"%"});
var sRotMidX = sLeft+sWidth*fmidX, sRotMidY=sTop+sHeight*fmidY;
```